# Bluemix SSO Node.JS: Social Media Authentication

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

Bluemix; Node.js; SSO; CWOAU0062E

## I've been focusing on man sample apps for SSO but personally could never get it to work.

#### Getting Error message: **CWOAU0062E: The OAuth service provider could not redirect the request because the redirect URI was not valid. Contact your system administrator to resolve the problem.**

the URL at this point is :https://mzsso-yyyyyyyyyyyy.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=cWs2hkNjHz&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmzibmsso.mybluemix.net%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Fcallback&scope=openid%20openid

(note that xxxxx, yyyyy, zzzzz, etc are my masked private identifiers...

1) error message: CWOAU0062E: The OAuth service provider could not redirect the request because the redirect URI was not valid. Contact your system administrator to resolve the problem.
**This occurs moments after I click on my /login url**...

2) no "integrate" in my bluemix portals, but I'm using the "new bluemix portals"

3) google tested, and validated ok using the validate button in Bluemix

4) facebook tested, and validated ok using the validate button in Bluemix

5) all samples and support that I am exploring on-line seem to be + 1 year old, and all my combinations/variants of the code result in this same error message.

6) Will it work for local testing (note the lack of https for local dev) (will I need to add "localhost:3000" to the redirect question in google?

6a) running locally doesn't support https, will this impact any ability to run locally for the purposes of development?

6b) currently I need to frequently *cf push* my app because of my uncertainty and general troubles with SSO. I've lost confidence in trying to test this locally since it fails on the server with a barebone project.

7) Is there a difference between the terms "callback url" and "redirect url" (context from google, bluemix, and callback_url)

8) My code makes no direct references to "google" or "facebook".  Am I forgetting something obvious or is the idea behind Bluemix SSO to make my app provider-agnostic?

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var mzSession = require('express-session');

var passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;

app.use(mzSession({
    secret : 'mzSSOSource',
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized : true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

var cfenv = require("cfenv");
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
var appServices = appEnv.getServices();

var SSOList = appServices;

if (SSOList.SingleSignOn === undefined) {
    SSOList = {
        "SingleSignOn" : [ {
            "credentials" : {
                "secret" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
                "tokenEndpointUrl" : "https://mzsso-yyyyyyyyyyyy.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/token",
                "authorizationEndpointUrl" : "https://mzsso-yyyyyyyyyy.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize",
                "issuerIdentifier" : "yyyyyyyyyy.iam.ibmcloud.com",
                "clientId" : "zzzzzzzzzz",
                "serverSupportedScope" : [ "openid" ]
            },
            "syslog_drain_url" : null,
            "label" : "SingleSignOn",
            "provider" : null,
            "plan" : "professional",
            "name" : "mzSSO",
            "tags" : [ "security", "ibm_created", "ibm_dedicated_public" ]
        } ]
    };
}

var SSOEntryCreds = SSOList.SingleSignOn[0].credentials;

var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-idaas-openidconnect').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
    authorizationURL : SSOEntryCreds.authorizationEndpointUrl,
    tokenURL : SSOEntryCreds.tokenEndpointUrl,
    clientID : SSOEntryCreds.clientId,
    scope : 'openid',
    response_type : 'code',
    clientSecret : SSOEntryCreds.secret,
    callbackURL : 'https://mzibmsso.mybluemix.net/auth/sso/callback',
    skipUserProfile : true,
    issuer : SSOEntryCreds.issuerIdentifier
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        done(null, profile);
    });
});
passport.use(Strategy);

app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {}));

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    else {
        return next();
    }
}

app.get('/auth/sso/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    var redirect_url = req.session.originalUrl;
    console.log(redirect_url);
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
        successRedirect : redirect_url,
        failureRedirect : '/failure',
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/hello', ensureAuthenticated, function(request, response) {
    response.send('Hello, ' + request.user['id'] + '!\n' + '<a href="/logout">Log Out</a>');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/failure', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Login failed');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<a href="/auth/sso/callback">Sign In with a SIS</a>');
});

app.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, function() {
    console.log('Server listening: ' + JSON.stringify({
        'url' : appEnv.url,
        'bind' : appEnv.bind,
        'port' : appEnv.port
    }));
});
console.log('Server Script Completed');
```

Comment: Please check to see, if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602143/unable-to-get-sso-working-for-nodejs-in-bluemix

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the callback URL doesn't match with what be set in the return to URL for application configuration.
See this answer for reference:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/175319/why-sso-can-not-work.html

For your question #1 -  The "Integrate" panel is only available in the context of the application dashboard. Once you login into bluemix, you need to click on the Application's SSO service icon, not the SSO service itself.

For #7  The value for callback_url and the return to URL ( from the application Dashboard) should be the same.  The return to URL will become redirect_uri of this link the posted
https://mzsso-yyyyyyyyyyyy.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=cWs2hkNjHz&**redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmzibmsso.mybluemix.net%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Fcallback**&scope=openid%20openid

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I've been investigating that reference URL (from developer.ibm.com) and it seems like they ran into a very similar lssue.  it looks like they had some stale URI from the SSO service. ... What would be a typical URL?  I was using the auth/callback url from various samples/tutorials, but this URL not the SSO configuration call-back url, which is a very different ibmcloud url.

Would you know of an actual working example with code that's not +2 years old?  I'm thinking that my packages might be the problem since I'm using versions "latest" across the board.

Comment: Having the same issue and it has been really testing my patience. Do you get to see the SSO page at all where you can punch in your login credentials or is it showing you this error, as soon as you tap on the long button/link?

Comment: When I tried to simulate this problem locally, I noticed this issue is primarily caused by "&scope=openid%20openid" at the end of redirect_uri. I guess that needs to be handled to fix this issue?

Comment: UPDATES!
Bluemix UI is brutally un-intuitive.  When you go to the SSO Service from the Console >> Security >> yourSSOService, there is no Integrate option: https://app.box.com/s/kkl7sawvb6b6dglv04s0x49i5a5f2dzu

However when you go to the SSO Component via the App, YourComputeApp >> Connections >> yourSSOService, now the Integrate option appears: https://app.box.com/s/i74hiy24zgwdyvb2zqsb00lvmy1ayihx

I entered a return-to url, which is my ...auth/sso/callback, and now I get locked into a *LOOPING REDIRECT SITUATION*.  It results in a failed auth...

Comment: Still cannot get it to work. 
Made my app work with LinkedIn, Facebook, GitHub, Twitter in 30 mins. Its been 1 day of the same error with BlueMix SSO. I bet IBM cannot make this better than how they have got it out there

Comment: Krishnan, can you please post some details as follows:
1) your overall bluemix app URL.
2) the callback URL in your Strategy constructor ({callbackURL : ???});
3) the "Return-to URL" from the SSO Integrate properties for your bluemix app.

Comment: Here you go
Constructor - https://krishnodejs.mybluemix.net/auth/sso/callback
Settings UI in SSO - https://krishnodejs.mybluemix.net/hello

Comment: If you want to check my entire code and error, here you go
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602143/unable-to-get-sso-working-for-nodejs-in-bluemix

Comment: @MarkZlamal Were you able to fix yours? Did you get it working?

Comment: @Krishnan, congrats on getting it working.  For me, while I did get past this redirect_URL problem, I now am faced with ** Cannot assign to read only property 'accessToken' ** which occurs in my process.nextTick(..) call inside the strategy. Apparently **"profile.accessToken = accessToken;"** will not work because PROFILE is read-only.  I'll probably open a new Stackoverflow question on this if I don't find an existing question already.

Comment: Please do. Let me see if I can help you on this

Comment: @MarkZlamal   I am glad you got it sorted out.
As I mentioned above, you have to access the App configuration from the SSO service icon within the application Context.  An SSO service instance may have more than one bound applications.  Changing it from the application context make it apply to a specific application.  The return-to URL must match with what you configured in NodeJS application's callback_url.
BlueMix doc link yet on how to configure Application for SSO service, I hope it helps:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/configure_apps.html#tsk_integratingapp